# Save videos using uiimagepickercontroller without changings its created date

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using uiimagepicker to save video to my application bundle. But after saving that, the created date of the video is changed. My requirement is just to copy that video to my folder without changing its created date.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *path = NSHomeDirectory();
    NSString *img_temp_name=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"] stringByAppendingString:@".mov"];
    NSString *full_path=[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:img_temp_name];

    if([imageData writeToFile:full_path atomically:YES]) {
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you use NSFileManager to help you?

I assume that you're not going to be allowed just to move the movie but if you copy it, does it preserve some file information?

```
NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
NSString *path = NSHomeDirectory();
NSString *img_temp_name=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"] stringByAppendingString:@".mov"];
NSString *full_path=[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:img_temp_name];

NSURL *dst = [NSURL fileURLWithString:full_path];

NSError *error = nil;
NSFileManager *manager = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];
BOOL success = [manager copyItemAtURL:url toURL:dst error:&error];

if (NO == success || error) {
    NSLog(@"Could not copy : %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Not working....
I made changes to my code like

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
   
NSString *path = NSHomeDirectory();
NSURL *dst = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSError *error = nil;
NSFileManager *manager = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];
BOOL success = [manager copyItemAtURL:url toURL:dst error:&error];
 
 if (NO == success || error) {
  NSLog(@"Could not copy : %@", error);
 }
}

Comment: Log  Could not copy : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=262 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 262.)"

Comment: What are your `url` and `dst` values when you do the copy?

Comment: src=<CFURL 0x5a21720 [0x1135400]>{type = 15, string = assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000001&ext=JPG, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}

dst=<CFURL 0x5852fa0 [0x1135400]>{type = 15, string = file://localhost/Users/xxx-xxxx/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/4.3/Applications/C5E74E0F-91D0-4A8D-8AA3-1EFF276C6AED/Documents/1.jpg, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}

Comment: Guess it doesn't recognise the assets-library url then. Sorry my answer won't work!

Comment: Thanks Dean for your help..
Is there any way to show videos in uiimagepicker filtered by created date??

Comment: No idea - why not ask it on stack overflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that as part of the picking process the video is reencoded.  This changes the creation date.  I would also like to know if it is possible to getbthis info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get videos as NSData.
It uses the Photos framework as ALAssetLibrary is deprecated as of iOS9:

> IMPORTANT
>
> The Assets Library framework is deprecated as of iOS 9.0. Instead, use the Photos framework instead, which in iOS 8.0 and later provides more features and better performance for working with a user’s photo library. For more information, see Photos Framework Reference.

```
import Photos

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    
    if let referenceURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL {
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([referenceURL], options: nil)
        if let phAsset = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset {
            PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(phAsset, options: PHVideoRequestOptions(), resultHandler: { (asset, audioMix, info) -> Void in
                if let asset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                    let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: asset.URL)
                    
                    // optionally, write the video to the temp directory
                    let videoPath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "tmpMovie.MOV"
                    let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
                    let writeResult = videoData?.writeToURL(videoURL, atomically: true)
                    
                    if let writeResult = writeResult where writeResult {
                        print("success")
                    }
                    else {
                        print("failure")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```